# CodeIgniter controller naming confusion

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I need some help structuring my website.

I have a `home.php` controller that just draws the home page. The `members.php` controller is basically handling everything else from checking if a user is logged in, to sending users to the signup page, and data to the `membership_model.php`.

My question is: Should I arrange this differently? Shouldn't my `home.php` controller be responsible for loading the correct views when a user clicks a given link.  If the user clicks a REGISTER button, shouldn't the `home.php` controller load the template of the registration page? I just feel its wrong to have the controller that loads the home page do only that.

If I have a register method in the home page controller, and also have a `register.php` controller to handle things that happen from the registration page, is that okay? Is that proper?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: IF it works, then it probably doesn't matter. Now go accept some previous answers please.

Answer (score 3):

You should split it according to your needs. There's not a "best" way of doing so.

Use the home controller to handle the visual part of the website and leave another to handle all user related actions (like userpanel, register, login, etc).
At least that's what i'd do. There's not a recipe for this

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about having a home controller that only loads the home page. If thats what you need thats what you need. It's better to keep things organised and have a file with little in it than stick in some other place that makes no sense.

Like Nicolas I use a users.php controller which does, login, logout, register etc...